# Expo Publish on Android using Google App Signing broken

Tags: react-native, build, expo, exponent

I have successfully published my app as a bundle (aab) on the PlayStore. I wanted to install a small update after a few days, because there are problems with the keyboard. I have executed "expo build:android -t app-bundle" as usual.

Afterwards I tried to upload directly via the cli (after it failed with the message that the fingerprint is invalid) also via the PlayStore. I got the same message that the fingerprint of the upload key does not match.

I have tried to download the upload key, but I get the following message:

> expo fetch:android:upload-cert

```
There is no valid Keystore defined for this app Writing upload key to /my/path/to/xxxxx_upload_cert.pem

keytool exited with non-zero code: 1
```

I had "Google App Signing" enabled in PlayStore from the beginning, even before I knew anything about an "expo opt-in" command. There was already an upload certificate in my PlayStore. I let Expo manage the entire process and never generated anything myself.

Now I'm stuck here and don't know what to do. I can't download any hashes or upload certificates, nor can I update my app. This is absolute horror right now. I had extra Expo manage everything to avoid problems right here.

How can we fix the problem now?

```
  Expo CLI 3.11.3 environment info:
    System:
      OS: macOS 10.14.6
      Shell: 3.2.57 - /bin/bash
    Binaries:
      Node: 10.16.3 - /usr/local/bin/node
      Yarn: 1.13.0 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
      npm: 6.13.2 - ~/Gitlab/xxxx/xxxx/xxxx-app/bin/npm
      Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
    IDEs:
      Android Studio: 3.5 AI-191.8026.42.35.5977832
      Xcode: 11.3/11C29 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
    npmPackages:
      expo: ^36.0.0 => 36.0.0 
      react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0 
      react-native: https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-36.0.0.tar.gz => 0.61.4 
      react-navigation: ^4.0.10 => 4.0.10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue got addressed by the expo team and is resolved

https://forums.expo.io/t/can-update-app-in-playstore-problems-with-signing-and-fingerprint/31520/4

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the `keytool exited with non-zero code: 1` just downloading and installing the last JDK from [here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-downloads.html).